# Check if a role is granted using a regular expression in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

My roles are something like `SEND_SMS_100`, `SEND_SMS_200` or more in general `SEND_SMS_X` where `X` is an integer. It's the maximum number of small text message that an user can send over a month. An user should have at max one of this role. I'm looking for:

- `ensure SEND_SMS_X` is granted
- extract `X` integer

AFAIK this will not support regular expression based search:

```
$this->get('security.context')->isGranted($roleName);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is bad design - this shouldn't be something that is controlled by roles.

You should probably have a $smsPerMonth property on your user entity so you can call getSmsPerMonth() instead of using many different roles to figure out how many SMS messages a user can send.